# I posted an answer I now believe to be incorrect, if not bad. What to do?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I posted an answer to my own question on Stack Overflow, which after some additional work, I now believe to be incorrect, if not harmful.  I know I can delete it, but a fairly large effort went into to producing it and the reasons why it's wrong are probably interesting in and of themselves.

The system won't let me down-vote my own answer, just as it won't let me up-vote it.  Is there anything to be done other than deleting it?

Comment: Can you share the link to the answer?

Comment: I already modified the answer.  In essence I deleted it without doing a delete.  Within the same answer link is a whole new answer.  Here is the link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476703/log4j2-logging-of-code-in-ejb-jar-on-jboss-eap-7?answertab=active#tab-top .  You can make out what it used to be sort of by reading the revisions tab.  The "diff engine" chopped it up something awful, but if you study it carefully, you can see it's a totally new answer.

Comment: You can view without the diff engine

Comment: I'd move those details into the question.  It'd be annoying if I answered and found out that I'd gone down the same road, but didn't realize it because I wasn't looking for that kind of info in an answer.

Comment: which details are you referring to?

Answer (score 5):

The fact that it's your answer to your question is, I think, not really relevant. The same applies to *any* answer that you might give.

Although downvoting your own answer is in a sense altruistic, it might be tricky to implement and the possible frequency of use of that feature is questionable. It would also introduce an asymmetry in the downvoting / upvoting mechanism because clearly upvotes on your own questions and answers would still remain unsupported.

You could always improve the answer by making edits. Surely that's the best thing to do?

Otherwise the correct thing to do is to delete it. There are plenty of deleted questions and answers on Stack Overflow, for example, with large net positive upvotes - you'll be able to see those once your reputation reaches 10,000. I'm sure that more honourable members of the community will downvote it, at a small cost to their reputation.

As a final remark, being able to downvote your own answers could introduce spurious gaming: one could answer, immediately downvote that answer, and hope for a sympathetic upvoter.

Comment: The only improvement I could make would be to say, "Don't go down this path".  My use case is unusual, nobody else has submitted an answer, and the real answer is probably "find a different way to do this."  So deletion is probably best followed (or preceded) by writing another answer to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the relevant part of the answer into your question, as part of showing the research you've done so far. That is even mentioned in one of the basic [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts):

> #### When should I ask a question?
>
> Good questions are always welcome, provided you have done your homework first, and *can share the results of your research with us.*

(emphasis mine)